# php mysql query is null or empty

Tags: php, mysql, sql, command

I need to select from videos where status is 0 and error is empty or null. So my sql is:

`SELECT * FROM videos WHERE 'status' = 0 and 'error' IS NULL`
But the result is not same on my mind. 
Sorry for my English

Comment: do not surround your fields with quote `'`. if you have to escape the field name, use tick `

Comment: run your query in your database and see the result

Comment: http://postimg.org/image/f2av10zcp/
please look this image no rows retuened

Comment: what is the datatype of status ? int, varchar or enum ?

Comment: i can't understand the question

Comment: I meant the datatype of the column

Comment: i understood structure. am I true?

Comment: yes check the table structure and let me know the datatype of status

Comment: Structure: http://s8.postimg.org/nyg6nrq91/structure.png

Comment: Ok posted the answer and this should work now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok the query is not working since the `status` is `enum` and you need to wrap the value in single quotes so the query should be

```
SELECT * FROM videos WHERE `status` = '0' and `error` IS NULL
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Incorrect quotes on the field names. You used `'`, which turns them into strings. You want backticks (`` ` ``), or none at all, since neither of your field names are reserved words:

```
SELECT * FROM videos WHERE status = 0 and error IS NULL
SELECT * FROM videos WHERE `status` = 0 and `error` IS NUL
```